# Reading EXIF data from image using Picasso in android

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-image, exif

I have the following code that downloads an image from an URL and displays it in an imageView:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
          .load(mImagesUrls[mPosition])
          .resize(500, 500)
          .centerCrop()
          .into(mSlideImage);
```

But apart from displaying the image, I'm also needing to retrieve some EXIF data. Googling how to do this for android lead me to the "ExifInterface" class but it's constructors are as follows:

> 1. ExifInterface(String filename)
>
>    - Reads Exif tags from the specified image **file**.
> 2. ExifInterface(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor)
>
>    - Reads Exif tags from the specified image **file descriptor**.
> 3. ExifInterface(InputStream inputStream)
>
>    - Reads Exif tags from the specified image **input stream**.

How could I get any of the arguments these constructors require ? all I could find with Picasso was a way to get the load the image as a bitmap, which doesn't seem to support EXIF data.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, have you got a solution?

Comment: Sadly no, never got around to figuring this out. Project was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help but I have made an example that in my case works, but it's just an example:

```
public void transformPicture(final File file, final OnImageReady onImageReady) {
float rotation = 0;
try {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
    int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
    switch (orientation){
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90: {
        rotation = -90f;
        break;
    }
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180: {
        rotation = -180f;
        break;
    }
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270: {
        rotation = 90f;
        break;
    }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Picasso.get().load(file)
    .resize(getTargetMaxSize(), getTargetMaxSize())
    .centerInside()
    .rotate(rotation)
    .into(myView);
}
```

And remember that you can read exif only from files not from network.
Also can see [Exif Orientation Tag](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html)

You can get ExifInterface even like this:

```
String fileName = "/path/file.any";
ExifInterface exifInterface1 = new ExifInterface(fileName);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
ExifInterface exifInterface3 = new ExifInterface(fis);
```